# shell_exec not respecting open_basedir

Tags: php, linux, apache

I am creating a shared hosting but unfortunatelly I need to allow users to use shell_exec. The problem is that with that command they can read almost any file in my server, including other websites's files! How can I make shell_exec obey open_basedir that I set in vhosts file?

Comment: Implement fastcgi or suphp so the php processes run as the specific user. That will help security significantly.

Answer (score 0):

I beleive that there is no easy way to do this. In order to block your clients to a specific directory, you will have to block the running PHP running user. (probably apache or www-data)

You will have to implement a module or a way to run each instance with a user that you can chroot to your specific path.

Comment: Thank you sir. If I cant allow shell_exec because of the security problems, I think I could disable if in my php.ini but if some client needs to use it I can give them a new name to the funciton like shell_exec_fdslkfjd but HOW do I make thisfunction name work as shell_exec?

Comment: Use FastCGI and disable shell_exec via the pool definitions in php-fpm.conf. Then just don't remove it for the pool of the user who should have shell_exec.

Answer (score -1):

You can restrict on basedir and specific root basedir that user can access to. PHP need `/tmp` dir for sessions so don't forget to this regulative. Here is code for the sample and you can add directories and allow it:

```
open_basedir = /home/users/some_user/public_html:/tmp
```

This is globally on PHP but you can on Apache users hosting environment and set for each user to specify `open_basedir`:

```
 php_admin_value open_basedir "/home/some_user:/usr/lib/php:/usr/php5/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php5/lib/php:/tmp"
```

Make sure that path is available and check is working. Don't forget add `/tmp`.